# Not getting along with Spanish professor. Professor is condescending, and picks favorites. I feel I have enough evidence to do something

Tags: professorship, undergraduate, bachelor, lecture-teaching-method

I am in a Spanish Translation class at a good public university.

Background: I am a white male and a Spanish/Chemistry double major. I plan to pursue a PhD in Chemistry or teach at the high school level, and Spanish is pure enjoyment. I am engaged in this class. I do every single reading, and try really hard to participate. I do not give her any "sass" (and if I did, that still doesn't justify taking points off in direct contradiction of her assigned readings). I have asked her already how to be more polite, and she tells me I am fine.

Early in the class, there were some strange vibes. Since then, there have been numerous instances, so for brevity I will only mention the ones that stick out most.

1: She marks me off two points for using the word "Filipina" in a journalism translation, claiming it's not an english word. I find it in the Merriam-Webster dictionary as well as in hundreds of New York Times (reliable english journalism source). She awards me only one of two points back for this, and when I question it she says it is "non-negotiable."

2: One day, she asks our opinion about a "translation tidbit". I said I liked it and thought it was poetic, and she proceeds to laugh out loud assuming I'm joking. She then says in an incredibly exaggerated and melodramatic way "I admire your courage for speaking up in class but that is incorrect." Some awkward silence passes and she says, again loudly to the whole class, "Are you embarrassed?" in an incredibly condescending manner.

3: On a quiz, I translated the phrase "Diagnosticar un niño es separar la familia" or something similar as "To diagnose a child is to separate the family." She marks me off two points, claiming she "wanted the gerund" and **cited certain textbook pages.** On these **same pages**, the book clearly reads "the infinitive in Spanish can be translated as the gerund or as the infinitive in english." I present her with this direct evidence and again she says "I wanted the gerund. Non-negotiable."

4: During our most recent quiz, our task is to translate an idiom. She writes an idiom on the board, relating to January 6th which is apparently a holiday in the Spanish-speaking world. I very politely ask her for the meaning of this holiday, and she says condescendingly to the class "I would expect an advanced to student to know what this cultural day is. I can't just give you the answer." Several other students raise their hands and admit to not knowing the cultural reference. She then tells us what it is, and angrily says "You're welcome for the answer. Have a good spring break."

5: While reassuring one of her favorites about a missed assignment, she talks about the "class participation" part of our grade (10%). She openly says "this is where I can give my favorite students a little bit of a boost." She makes direct eye contact with me during this. That's what spurred me to write this.

Beyond these instances, other students have commented to me that they also notice her favoritism and hostility toward me. She has a general air of condescension toward everyone, but it's worse with me. I don't know what to do. I am giving my all, and objectively earning A's according to her rubrics. I have an A in the class right now, but I can just sense that she's going to screw me with this "Participation grade", which is not valid because I participate more than almost everyone else in class.

Is there anything I can do? I feel like I have decent evidence and can bring in a fellow classmate to vouch for me if need be. I have no doubts they would take my side.

**Update: She gave me no feedback on my final paper draft and then proceed to make 80 edits to my revision, and then gave me a lower grade on the revision. I decided this lack of feedback was sufficient enough to go over her head.**

Comment: What is your objective here,  exactly?

Comment: I don't understand what being a white male has anything to do with your question.

Comment: Are you sure it is a good idea to post this publicly under your (presumably) real name?

Comment: @mdiener I assume that name & pic are fake, and that the real Derek Fulton is going to be rather embarrassed by the content that is being posted in his name.

Comment: Yeah I thought about it and I don't really see a reason why I should try to hide this post, this is my real name.

Comment: Going over her head now is asking for trouble. You have an A as it stands. Play the rest of the game patiently. None of what you posted strikes me as alarming. I dislike the "non-negotiable remarks" ... she ought to have explained why her approach is the favored one.  The teacher possibly sounds petty and condescending. I would keep your head down and let her cool off, then diffuse the situation with kindness. Be polite. Cater to her a bit. All you want is your A.

Comment: That's not true though, she is negatively encroaching on the academic experience of not only me, but many other students. I genuinely care more about that than my A.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I said I was a white male because this teacher behaves in clear observance of traditional gender dynamics, and acts significantly differently toward her male and female students. That is relevant to frame the context of the rest of my description.

Comment: Can somebody please explain why this was closed as an undergraduate-only question?

Comment: _Spanish is pure enjoyment_ — Then why are you concerned about losing points?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Others may disagree, but I think you should go over her head. When she's outright admitting that she plays favorites with the participation grade, her department should know. What they do with that information is hard to predict, but if such complaints become a pattern with this teacher, they (hopefully) have to do something about it. Plus, complaining now could put you on slightly firmer ground if she gives you a grade for the course that's low enough for you to want to challenge it.

If there's someone with a title like "Director of the Undergraduate Spanish Program," that's the person to complain to.

Comment: Going over the head is absolutely fine if he's already attempted to resolve the issue without success.

Comment: @guifa: The open statement to the class about the participation portion of the grade is sufficient grounds to go outside of the class.

Comment: @aeismail I agree, it wasn't that type of if statement :-)